# New three.js release don't work with blender model anymore?

Tags: html, 3d, blender, three.js

I used to export blender models to use them in with three.js. That was in the time of r47 and before. But today I updated three.js to the latest release r49, it doesn't work anymore neither for the r48, I mean the same simple code that used to show me the model in the browser  just because I updated three.js doesn't show anything now. How should I take that ? stay in the r47 or is there an issue that I don't know for new releases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to re-export with the latest Blender exporter.

Comment: Can you upload the test somewhere so it can be analysed?

Comment: You need to updated your code too. JSONLoader has changed a bit. Take a look at the code of this example to see what loader.load() expects now: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_materials_normal.html

Comment: Ok I will see, but I just want to note that, 99% of tutorials on internet are using r47, so when I wanted to look for the new version of the code I didn't find any help or anyone talking about it, oh wait sound great to make a blog about this...